# Micronaut serverless application with DynamoDB and Graal java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, micronaut, micronaut-aws

I'm working on a application which are running on AWS lambda and using Micronaut and GraalVM.
I started using the example provided by AWS in the [AWSLabs GitHub - PetStore - Micronaut](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-java-container/tree/master/samples/micronaut/pet-store) .
If I just clone this repo and using the SAM model, I'm able to run the application with no error, but if I try to add the DynamoDB dependency,
I got the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration`

This is the DynamoDB dependency that I'm using: `compile ('com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:1.11.762')`

I've tried many things, change the DynamoDB version, add the AWSSdk core dependency, add this class to the `reflect.json` file, using JDK 8, JDK 11, but none of them works.

I don't know what I need to do to have DynamoDB working with Micronaut and GraalVM.

I'm using IntelliJ and through the IDE I'm able to see that this class is on my classpath, there is no compile error.

Thank you.